# Short story about scientists playing grooves on old pottery like an old vinyl record

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, technology

Read a long time ago so not recent, maybe in the 1970s or 1980s. It might have been Bradbury, but maybe not.

Some kind of researchers (anthropologists? physicists?) figure out how to play the grooves on a wheel-turned pot (people have used for more than 5 thousand years!) with a stylus/needle just like you play old-school records. They're hoping they'll hear something really interesting, but it turns out to be totally mundane and boring. A guy comes and talks with the potter, they gossip idly about neighbors. My recollection is that the potter lived in medieval England.

Comment: Was this story science fiction or fantasy? I'm not seeing any SF/F elements in the description you've given so far.

Comment: Off possible relation: http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/mythbusters-database/ancient-voices-recorded-into-pottery/

Comment: By a SF author, published in a SF collection.  Also speculative and counter-factual...

Comment: @DavidW Sorry, I'd misunderstood the description. Somehow I didn't realise they were hearing voices from hundreds of years ago recorded on the pot.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but the concept of sound being encoded in a pot is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaeoacoustics#Past_interpretations_controversy); it lists several works of fiction with the premise (including "Time Shards").  I first heard of it in the extremely meta _X-Files_ episode ["Hollywood AD"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_A.D.)

Comment: This reminds me of a TV show in the 1980s called "The Wizard."  From what It was about an genius inventor who would use his toys/gadgets to solve various crimes.  In one episode, he listened to a previously-held conversation that had been unknowingly recorded onto a pottery vase.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Neither did I. When I read that "it turns out to be totally mundane and boring," I assumed that it was just static, as hearing *words* (as in the suggested answer) would not be mundane nor boring at all for the researcher! No matter what they actually said.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235374/looking-for-a-story-about-ancient-sound-recordings-in-stone (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 36):

I think this was "[Time Shards](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57461)" ([link to story online](https://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/time-shards/)) by Gregory Benford.  (It was originally published in [*Universe 9*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?33562) (1979), edited by Terry Carr.)

***Researchers figure out how to play the grooves on a wheel-turned pot***

> Brooks stooped forward. When he peered closer he could see the smooth finish was an illusion. A thin thread ran around the pot, so fine the eye could scarcely make it out. The lines wound in a tight helix. In the center of each delicate line was a fine hint of blue. The jug had been incised with a precise point.
>
> [...]
>
> Hart pressed a switch and the turntable began to spin. He watched it for a moment, squinting with concentration. Then he reached down to the side of the turntable housing and swung up the stylus manifold. It came up smoothly and Hart locked it in just above the spinning red surface of the pot.

***My recollection is that the potter lived in medieval England.***

> “Who made it?”
>
> “Near as I can determine, somebody in a co-operative of villages, barely Christian. Still used lots of pagan decorations. Got them scrambled up with the cross motif a lot.”
>
> “You’ve gotten . . . words?”
>
> “Oh, sure. In early English, even.”

Answer (score 5):

The wikipedia page on [archaeoacoustics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaeoacoustics) references:

> Rudy Rucker's 1981 short story "Buzz" includes a small section of
>   audio recovered from ancient Egyptian pottery.

in addition to Time Shards (as answered by DavidW) and various tv shows who used the technique.

Comment: This answer sort of reads as more of a comment on the other answer and various other possibilities this could be. It might be better if you edited it to focus solely on "Buzz" and why that matches.

Comment: "Buzz" is about a kind of self-replicating alien waveform that, when played back, takes over the world.